# Postfix: limit INCOMING rate

Tags: postfix, rate-limiting

I have a Postfix 2.11 server listed as an MX-server for a wildcard domain, `*.domain.com`

I need to limit the **incoming** rate per particular subdomain/destination address. So if someone starts sending 1000s of emails to same address- there's a delay being added.

PS. I tried googling but all I can find is - rate-limiting of **outgoing** smtp-emails, not incoming (smtpd)...

Answer (score 1):

you use 3rd party policy plugins

http://www.postfix.org/addon.html

An example of a [rate limiting](http://postfwd.org/ratelimits.html) with postfwd.

Comment: DKIM, SPF, greylists? The incoming emails are legit. Not spam. I just need to delay bulk emails, so the database server doesn't go crazy.

Comment: then just the rate limiting, you gave no insight to your existing policies

Comment: I didn't, sorry, but I was pretty explicit tho: "if someone sends tons of email - ADD A DELAY" . Does SPF/DKIM/blacklists or dmarc add a delay? :))

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use **postfwd** as policy_daemon; the site even has some examples:

http://postfwd.org/ratelimits.html

Comment: which is my link...

Comment: Yes but its No milter

Comment: ah true, updated

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a third party policy daemon.

Policyd v2.0, "Cluebringer", is able to do exactly what you want/need: http://wiki.policyd.org

Other daemons also have rate based limiting facilities, e.g. Rspamd and many others.

But face the truth: this is not what you really want.

What you really want is a dynamic blocking of senders which send too much mails per minute/etc.

This can be done by Postfix itself, take a look at anvil, herehttp://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html and here: http://www.postfix.org/anvil.8.html

Also putting postscreen in front of your real Postfix might help: http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html